# How to use default iOS images?

Tags: ios7, icons

I know how to use images in iOS application. But I don't know how to use default images like share or bookmark icons which are mention in developer site.

I want to use them. Do I need to download those set of images or those are available in Xcode?

If we have to download them, where I can get those icons?

Comment: Could you provide link to page where images that you asking are displayed?

Comment: Or it even better if you attach it the question.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/BarIcons.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH21-SW1

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56624333/5306470

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Developers haven't direct access to these images. I mean that you can't initialise image object like this:

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"name_of_system_image"];
```

But you can display some of images by using system types. For example you could init `UIBarButtonItem` with system types that provides standard icons:
[- (id)initWithBarButtonSystemItem:(UIBarButtonSystemItem)systemItem target:(id)target action:(SEL)action](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIBarButtonItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIBarButtonItem/initWithBarButtonSystemItem:target:action:)

Where `UIBarButtonSystemItem` provides such types:

> UIBarButtonSystemItemDone,
>   UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel,
>   UIBarButtonSystemItemEdit,
>   UIBarButtonSystemItemSave,
>   UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd,
>   UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace,
>   UIBarButtonSystemItemFixedSpace,
>   UIBarButtonSystemItemCompose,
>   UIBarButtonSystemItemReply,
>   UIBarButtonSystemItemAction,
>   UIBarButtonSystemItemOrganize,
>   UIBarButtonSystemItemBookmarks,
>   UIBarButtonSystemItemSearch,
>   UIBarButtonSystemItemRefresh,
>   UIBarButtonSystemItemStop,
>   UIBarButtonSystemItemCamera,
>   UIBarButtonSystemItemTrash,
>   UIBarButtonSystemItemPlay,
>   UIBarButtonSystemItemPause,
>   UIBarButtonSystemItemRewind,
>   UIBarButtonSystemItemFastForward,
>   UIBarButtonSystemItemUndo,
>   UIBarButtonSystemItemRedo,
>   UIBarButtonSystemItemPageCurl

Comment: Unfortunately in this case you cannot modify title and stuck with iOS default title for those images, correct?

Comment: Yes, @YuriS, you cannot change the title on the system items. This is because they are automatically "localized" for you: they will display in whatever language the user has set on their device. If you want to use your own text for the title, and you wanted to display the text in different languages, you would have to provide your own translations for your text.

Comment: You follow - https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibarbuttonsystemitem?language=objc

Answer (score 104):

Now starting from Swift 5.1 and Xcode 11 you can load 1 from over 1500 system images with the new UIImage Api `UIImage(systemName: "imageName")` which are vector based so no worries about qualities for different sizes

https://developer.apple.com/design/resources/

[image]

Comment: Thanks, for system images is systemName:String and for my assets images is name:String

Comment: But only wtih iOS 13.0 and greater. Any idea how to use it for iOS 11 or 12?

Comment: @Shree Ranga Raju Did you find out the answer?

Answer (score 19):

> Swift 5.1, Xcode 11

Here is one example of SF Symbols..About 1500 system images are provided by apple with different weights and scales.

```
let homeSymbolConfiguration = UIImage.SymbolConfiguration(pointSize: 55, weight: .black)
let homeImage = UIImage(systemName: "house", withConfiguration: homeSymbolConfiguration)
let width = homeImage?.size.width
let height = homeImage?.size.height
let homeButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: width!, height: height!))
homeButton.tintColor = UIColor.gray
homeButton.setImage(homeImage, for: .normal)
view.addSubview(homeButton)
```

Apple has provided a Mac app SF Symbols with all the system images. They all are in svg format means they are scalable. You can export and edit them.

Follow this WWDC 2019 Session 206.
https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/206/

Comment: Requires iOS 13 or above.

Comment: Unfortunately, you can’t use SF Symbols directly on iOS 12 and below as you can on iOS 13 and up. If you’d like to use any of the symbols on iOS 12 and below you need to export them from the SF Symbols Mac app and import them as regular assets in your Asset Catalog.

Answer (score 6):

**In swift : For System images , Simply do it**

```
imageView?.image = UIImage(systemName: "face.smiling")
```

**happy coding :) Hit Upvote**

System Resources are here: https://developer.apple.com/design/resources/

Answer (score 0):

For older iOS versions:

```
 if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
            cell.buttonImageIcon.image = UIImage(systemName: "info.circle.fill")
            cell.profileButton.tintColor = UIColor.white
            cell.profileButton.setTitle("PERSONAL INFORMATION", for: .normal)
        } else {
            // Fallback on earlier versions
        }
```

Comment: What is the fallback version?

Comment: Does not add anything to the answers from 2019. Would be improved with a link to https://happycoding.app/index.html or some actual fallback

Answer (score 0):

### How to use System Name Image (SF Symbols) ?

```
 lazy var scanImg: UIImageView = {
        let img = UIImageView()
        img.image = UIImage(systemName: "sensor.tag.radiowaves.forward")
        img.tintColor = .systemBlue
        img.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        return img
    }()
```