# How to set iOS 13 glyphs programmatically

Tags: swift, xcode11, ios13

Starting with iOS 13, Apple is providing a bunch of glyphs which can be [used](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/sf-symbols/overview/) *"everywhere you can use an image".*

> You can use SF symbols to represent tasks and types of content in a variety of specific places, such as navigation bars, toolbars, tab bars, context menus, and Home Screen Quick Actions. Throughout the rest of your app, you can use a symbol everywhere you can use an image.

I therefore expected this code to set a glyph as a `UIBarButtonItem`'s image:

```
shareButton = UIBarButtonItem(
            image: UIImage(named: "square.and.arrow.up"), // the name for the 'action' (Share) glyph
            style: .plain,
            target: self,
            action: #selector(mySelector))
```

But the app crashed with nil as the image wasn't found.
I tried appending `.png` to the image name, but it made no difference.

#### How can we set iOS 13 glyphs programmatically?

- Note: I installed the SF Symbols app and successfully set glyphs as the images for UIBarButtonItems *in Storyboard*.

Comment: I haven't tested it, but I think this is the call: `UIImage(systemName:)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Replace:

```
UIImage(named: "square.and.arrow.up")
```

With:

```
UIImage(systemName: "square.and.arrow.up")
```

This is now documented in [UIImage](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimage/configuring_and_displaying_symbol_images_in_your_ui)